# How can I use in my project some classes from other project?

Tags: android

I have an android project and I want to use some classes from another android project. How can I do that?
In my project I draw the road between 2 points.
From the new project I want to use some classes that help me draw more points on the map and tooltips with information for they.

Comment: Do you have access to the other project you are talking about?

Comment: We need more specifics to be able to answer. What Exactly are you tryin to do?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the other project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) containing the common part for the two projects. Make the two projects reference this Android library project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on your project -> New -> Package
2. Name the package `com.youname.yourapp.something`
3. Copy the classes you want to use in this project.
4. Use `import` to use copied classes.

Comment: I did the first three steps, but I have some errors in the new classes. Error: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You will need to copy all the resources including String, Layout etc. associated with the copied classes into the new project.